# Why does the webpage I created have whitespace on mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I tried writing some code for a webpage and it looked good on desktop view but I noticed that in mobile view, the right half of the page is whitespace. To fix this, I have tried to make the parent elements width '100%' and the child element width to 'auto', as you can see from the code below.

```css
*   {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li, a, button, input    {
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: azure;
    font-weight: 500;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 7%;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo   {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.nav    {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav li a {
    transition: all 0.35s ease 0s;
}

.nav li a:hover     {
    color: greenyellow;
}

button  {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    color: azure;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover    {
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.box    {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: azure;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.3);
    color: black;
}


.box input  {
    width: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background: transparent;
}

h1  {
    color: greenyellow;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: auto;
}

p   {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

main    {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    padding: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <input class="box" type="text" placeholder="search">
    <a href="#"><button>Search</button></a>
</header>
<main>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Our app will help Road desing engineers to manage traffic. 
        This app will use AI technology to plan roads and traffic lights, 
        so you won't have to wait in traffic.
    </p>
</main>
```

Comment: Well, on mobile you will abviously not have the space you have on desktop, and you will need to keep that in mind and reduce your spacing, paddings, and perhaps even hide parts behind buttons or by focus (like a searchbar could just be the search icon and if you focus on it, expand and hide other things that aren't relevant). You should have a look into media queries.

Comment: You have to play with padding and display:flex. Check with browser inspection tool and you will see why it is taking gap. Gap is because of header extra padding.

Comment: You have 100px padding (on all sides) in your `main` element – that's a lot on a mobile screen (left and right = 200px just for padding – on most mobile screens that's more than half of the width). use media queries to define less padding for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS utilizes @media queries to adapt styles for various screen sizes. By defining the same CSS classes with different properties within these queries, you can tailor your styling specifically for smaller screens.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .nav li {
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
    .box, .logo {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    main {
        padding: 50px 20px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 50px; /* Adjust based on your preference */
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just append margin-bottom:2% to .box class and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query css to fix responsive screen issues, have a look changed code.

```css
*   {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li, a, button, input    {
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: azure;
    font-weight: 500;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 7%;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
}

.logo   {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav    {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.nav li a {
    transition: all 0.35s ease 0s;
}

.nav li a:hover     {
    color: greenyellow;
}

button  {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    color: azure;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover    {
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.search    {    
    padding: 10px 20px;    
}


.search input  {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: azure;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.3);
    color: black;
    margin-right:10px;
}

h1  {
    color: greenyellow;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: auto;
}

p   {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

main    {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    padding: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
main {padding: 20px;}
h1{font-size: 50px; margin: 20px 0;}
p{font-size: 16px;}
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="logo">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="search">
    <input class="box" type="text" placeholder="search">
    <button>Search</button>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Our app will help Road desing engineers to manage traffic. 
        This app will use AI technology to plan roads and traffic lights, 
        so you won't have to wait in traffic.
    </p>
</main>
```